# Selenium script execution is very slow in case no of rows are increases in Excel(XLSX) sheet

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I have written selenium scripts for my project and when i started running around 80 test cases and each test case having 100 steps then it is very slow but if i run with 10 test cases with same 100 steps for each test cases,execution is very fast,can any one help me how to resolve this type of issue,below is the excel reading class and in driver class we are getting values in string values and pass into application.

All my test cases steps are mentioned in excel file like below

```
1.Open Browser for this Browser keyword
2.Open URl for this openApp keyword
3.Wait for Username for this waitElement keyword
4.Enter Username for this typeText keyword. etc
```

same follows upto completion of test cases flow with 100 sheets for 100 test cases.

```
package Utilities;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class ExcelFileUtil {

    XSSFWorkbook wb;

    // It will load all the excel sheet & it will instantiate that particular
    // workbook

    public ExcelFileUtil(String file) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("InputSheet.xlsx");
        File files = new File(file);
        OPCPackage pkg =OPCPackage.open(files.getAbsolutePath());
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
    }

    public int rowCount(String sheetname) {
        return wb.getSheet(sheetname).getLastRowNum();
    }

    public int colCount(String sheetname, int rowNo) {
        return wb.getSheet(sheetname).getRow(rowNo).getLastCellNum();
    }

    public String getData(String sheetname, int row, int column) {
        String data = null;
        if (wb.getSheet(sheetname).getRow(row).getCell(column).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {

            data = wb.getSheet(sheetname).getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();
        }

        else {
            int celldata = (int) wb.getSheet(sheetname).getRow(row).getCell(column).getNumericCellValue();

            data = String.valueOf(celldata);
        }

        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String sheetname, int row, int column, String str,String file) throws Exception {
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetname);

        Row rownum = sh.getRow(row);

        Cell cell = rownum.createCell(column);

        cell.setCellValue(str);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        wb.write(fos);

        fos.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Testng data provider ?If not try to go with that then you will not see any issue.
And one more thing if you don't want to go with testng then you have to use the either collections concept or store all your excel data in a 2 dimensional array and access the values one by one.

Below link has very finest example for  storing of data in hash map collection framework.
http://www.inviul.com/store-data-excel-sheet-hashmap/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not using Data Provider and this class is used to read excel data and i'm using keyword driven framework and all xpath for each steps are stored into the excel file ,Check updated question can you please provide Java code with collection as same as my excel reading methods..

Comment: Updated my answer above @RajeshOm.please check it.thanks

Comment: Mention URL i've seen but not usable in my case,Please send me the code in the same format which i've posted in the question.